# Batch JavaEE difference between 2 jobs and 2 tasks

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing

I have to code a batch in Java EE and I want to ask you if it's better to have a batch with 2 jobs or one job with 2 steps?

What is the difference between the two ways of implementing the batch?

Let me explain my situation:
I have to get the records from a db, then I elaborate them, update the record on the database and in the end I have to produce an output file with my updated records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in Java Batch, if you have a use case where two related tasks will execute together, you will probably want to define them as two steps within a single job.

If the job fails or is stopped, the batch container allows you to restart the job at the previous step you left off at, from a checkpoint into the input data stream. 
It also has a built-in conditional transition based on exit status (e.g. proceed to step 2 vs. fail the job on "bad" exit status from step 1).

You might end up needing to build this same orchestration yourself if you define two separate jobs.

You also get some benefits doing parameterization, e.g. if you have an output file in step 1 used as input in step 2 you can easily parameterize them with a single value.